# Performance of browser SVG with huge amount of elements

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, svg

I make simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8gb5/) example (which drown many rectangles and bind unique event to each) to explore SVG + JS performance.

With 10x10 = 100 elements performance are superior but with 100x300 my Firefox was frozen on 10 sec to build area and events have 1 sec delay to complete.

If I drown Gnatt chart for 100 task for 1 year (356 day) I have same issue!

Is there are any way to improve performance?

One way that I see is to avoid closures and use generic event handler.

Another way is to bind single event to SVG and calculate (X,Y) coordinate to determine which action to do.

Once more is to build SVG before putting it to DOM.

Any other suggestion?

Here complete code if fiddle was down:

```
<div id="rect"></div>
<div id="hint"></div>
```

and:

```
var wN = 50;
var hN = 50;

var w = 600;
var h = 400;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Common actions on SVG object.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function SVGlibBase() {
    this.value = null;
}
SVGlibBase.svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
// prim.attr("name") return attribute value
// prim.attr("name", "value") set attribute name to value, chaining
// prim.attr("name", null) remove attribute, chaining
// prim.attr({"name1", "value1", "name2", "value2", ...}) set attributes, chaining
SVGlibBase.prototype.attr = function(name, value) {
    if (typeof name === "object") {
        for (var i in name) {
            this.attr(i, name[i]);
        }
        return this;
    }
    if (typeof name === "string") {
        if (typeof value === "string" || typeof value === "number") {
            this.value.setAttribute(name, value);
        } else if (value === null) {
            this.value.removeAttribute(name);
        } else if (typeof value === "undefined") {
            return this.value.getAttribute(name);
        }
        return this;
    }
    throw new Error("name is absent");
}
// Put object to container.
SVGlibBase.prototype.putTo = function(container) {
    container.value.appendChild(this.value);
    return this;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main drawing area.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function SVGlibObj(w, h) {
    this.value = document.createElementNS(SVGlibBase.svgNS, "svg");
    this.value.setAttribute("version", "1.2");
    this.value.setAttribute("baseProfile", "tiny");
    this.value.setAttribute("width", w);
    this.value.setAttribute("height", h);
    this.value.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h);
}
SVGlibObj.prototype = Object.create(SVGlibBase.prototype);
SVGlibObj.prototype.putTo = function(container) {
    container.appendChild(this.value);
    return this;
}
SVGlibObj.prototype.put = function(child) {
    this.value.appendChild(child.value);
    return this;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Rectangle.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function SVGlibRect(x, y, w, h) {
    this.value = document.createElementNS(SVGlibBase.svgNS, "rect");
    this.value.setAttribute("x", x);
    this.value.setAttribute("y", y);
    this.value.setAttribute("width", w);
    this.value.setAttribute("height", h);
}
SVGlibRect.prototype = Object.create(SVGlibBase.prototype);

var svg = new SVGlibObj(w, h).putTo(document.getElementById("rect"));

function xy2c(x, y) {
    return "rgb(" + (x*113 & 0xff) +","+ (y*23 & 0xff) +","+ ((x*y*7) & 0xff) + ")";
}

function get_e(i, j) {
    return function() {
        console.log("%d x %d", i, j);
        document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = i+" X "+j;
    }
}

var dw = w / wN;
var dh = h / hN;
for (var i = 0; i < wN; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < hN; j++) {
        var rect = new SVGlibRect(dw*i, dh*j, dw, dh).attr("fill", xy2c(i, j)).putTo(svg);
        rect.value.addEventListener("mouseover", get_e(i, j), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need 30,000 elements visible on screen at the same time? If not can you just create the ones you need to be visible?

Comment: For lots of elements you should definitely use event delegation.

Comment: @RobertLongson If I bind events with data (through closure) I don't need to perform calculation to find association between element and its data. But seems that lead to performance issues...